# Extract specific fetch/XHR data from a GET request by python code

Tags: python, browser, get

I access a certain webpage via my browser. When I debug the networking session, I see that at some point the browser makes a certain request to a certain referred to an API (with defined headers/cookies by the host) and then I see at the fetch/XHR tab the specific JSON file that I need.

My question is how can I make in Python a program that creates a GET request, then renders it and create the following requests according to the JS code, and at the Background sniffs all of the incoming fetch/XHR data.

I would be glad for any kind of direction-specifically which Python libraries should I use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specifically what do you mean with "Background sniffs all of the incoming fetch/XHR data"? Do you want to use Python  to intercept and change all GET requests made by the website?

Comment: What I want is to create a Python Program that simultaniously Renders a webpage and Intercepts incoming data from that host. Just the same as when you Debug the Networking of a website with the browser debug tools :)